# VS 2010 + ReSharper 6.1 - Shortcut for inserting a new line?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper-6.1

In IntelliJ it is possible to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert a new line at the current curser position in the editor.

Does such a shortcut exist for VS + ReSharper?

Also I'd love to have the IntelliJ Shortcut to complete the current statement without jumping to the next line.

In IntelliJ

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> = Completes current statement without jumping to the next line.
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> = Only jumps to the next line.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> = Inserts a new line and moves the current line down.

Would love to have this for VS + ReSharper

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I did not get any answer to a related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295572/auto-complete-statement-without-newline).

Answer (score 4):

To your requirement:

> complete the current statement without jumping to the next line.

The shortest way I know is ***Ctrl+Shift+Enter***, ***Ctrl+L*** (if using VisualStudio scheme).

Answer (score 3):

Configure the shortcut Edit.LineOpenBelow

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, Ctrl+enter inserts a new line in VS (even without resharper)...